# Averaging binomial confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

I have a general statistical question. Three schools A, B, and C have 0.23, 0.56, and 0.8 fraction of female teachers. The upper and lower confidence intervals (CI) for the three schools can be tabulated as shown below:

```
school  female_instructors  upper_CI  lower_CI
A       0.33                0.53      0.13
B       0.55                0.65      0.45
C       0.80                0.90      0.70
```

If I were asked to report the average fraction of female instructors in the three schools combined I would have informed: (0.33+0.55+0.8)/3 or 0.56. How would I define the CI for the average fraction?? Average given CIs as well i.e. upper: 0.69 and lower:0.43?? Is this is the best way to do such calculations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Two points**

**First point:** You could also perform a *weighted average* of the proportion of female instructors at the three schools (e.g., if A has ten times as many total instructors as B and C combined, one might argue that it should count more heavily). For example, $(n_{A}\times 0.23 + n_{B}\times 0.56 + n_{C} \times 0.8)/(n_{A} + n_{B} + n_{C})$. If the total number of instructors at each institution is the same size, then the weighted average reduces to the simple arithmetic mean as in your example.

**Second point:** If you recall that for Bernoulli distribution, the variance is determined by $p$ (the proportion), as in $\sigma^{2}_{p}=p(1-p)$, so that $\sigma_{p}=\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, and $\sigma_{\hat{p}}=\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$ (where $n = n_{A} + n_{B} + n_{C}$), one could readily generate a CI (say $\hat{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sigma_{\hat{p}}$) under the assumption that A, B, and C are all drawn from the same population.

**Bonus point:** Agresti and Coull have shown that the nominal coverage of the CI I just indicated performs suboptimally for small $n$. They provide an alternative which gives better nominal CI coverage for $\hat{p}$ thus:

$$\tilde{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})\tilde{n}}$$

where $\tilde{n} = n+2z_{\alpha/2}$, and $\tilde{p} = \frac{\left(\Sigma x\right) +z_{\alpha/2}}{\tilde{n}}$. Understand that the use of $\tilde{p}$ is *purely instrumental*, and the Agresti-Coull confidence interval is for $\hat{p}$. As sample size gets big, the nominal coverage of the standard Wald-type CI and that of the Agresti-Coull CI converge. More details about these and other [binomial proportion confidence intervals on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

**References**

Agresti, A. and Coull, B. A. (1998). [Approximate is better than “exact” for interval estimation of binomial proportions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2685469.pdf). *The American Statistician*, 52(2):119–126.

Comment: +1 I'd only add that the Wikipedia page on [binomial proportion CI's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) has a fairly extensive discussion of various approximations for the small-$n$ case, including Agresti-Coull. Some people use the simple "add 2 successes and 2 failures" ... which I think is what Agresti-Coull gives with $z=2$.

Comment: @Glen_b excellent suggestion, will add the link. The 2 successes and 2 failures of the 95% Agresti-Coull CI, obtains because $2 \approx 1.96$.

Comment: +1. We can reverse-engineer the data even without knowing which CI method was used, because (1) the UCL and LCL are symmetrically placed around the proportions and therefore (2) for a sample size $n$ the UCL should exceed the proportion $p$ by approximately $Z_{0.975}\sqrt{p(1-p)}/\sqrt{n}$. Solving for $n$ (and rounding) gives $n\approx 21, 95, 61$, respectively. Therefore the fraction of females is approximately $0.33(21)+0.55(95)+0.80(61),$ or about $108$ out of $177$. We can erect a 95% CI around these data. Using the same crude Normal approximation gives $0.61$, 95% CI = $(0.54,0.68)$.

Comment: @whuber, I may not be understanding you, but no, at least for the Agresti-Coull CI, the interval for $\hat{p}$ is symmetric about $\tilde{p}$ (not $\hat{p}$).